# Can't resize APFS Container: Not enough free space in Container due to APFS limits or tidemarks

Tags: disk-utility, partition, apfs

When I try to resize my APFS container, I get the following error:

```
Error: -69531: There is not enough free space in the APFS Container for this
operation due to APFS limits or APFS tidemarks (perhaps caused by APFS Snapshot
usage by Time Machine)
```

I followed this guide:

[How to Resize Your APFS Container on macOS High Sierra](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/resize-your-apfs-container/)

**Is there any way to resize my APFS container without backing up to Time Machine, wiping the disk, then recreating the partitions?**

*More details below:*

Here is the output from the `diskutil apfs` utility when I attempt to resize:

```
$ sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 750g jhfs+ Extra 250g

Started APFS operation
[ - 0%................................................... ]

Aligning shrink delta to 250,240,966,656 bytes and targeting a new physical
store size of 749,999,996,928 bytes

Determined the minimum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS
Container to be 997,029,183,488 bytes

Error: -69531: There is not enough free space in the APFS Container for this
operation due to APFS limits or APFS tidemarks (perhaps caused by APFS Snapshot
usage by Time Machine)
```

Here is my `diskutil` configuration:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            380.3 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Here is the total of those volumes *(calculated manually by me)*:

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
                     TOTAL                             922.0 GB
```

And when I go to Disk Utility, press the "Partition" button in the toolbar, and manually enter a size for my main disk partition, it won't let me set it under 997 GB, leaving only 3 GB for new partitions:

[image: Disk Utility]

Answer (score 27):

This is the key part of the error message:

```
(perhaps caused by APFS Snapshot usage by Time Machine)
```

You must remove the local snapshots. First, list them:

```
$ tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
```

You may wish / need to delete local snapshots one by one from taking the date from the listing above:

```
$ tmutil deletelocalsnapshots 2018-07-14-211120
```

You can also thin them based on the amount of space you wish to reclaim by asking for a lot of space back:

```
$ tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999
```

Then, you can resize your APFS partition:

```
$ sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 750g
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @leesavage - I'm guessing my edit is correct to what you meant by `{date&time}` ?

Answer (score 5):

This should unlock the ability to resize your disk:

```
tmutil listlocalsnapshots / \
  | cut -d. -f4 \
  | xargs -n1 tmutil deletelocalsnapshots
```

It does the same thing as Neil's answer, except that it copy-pastes the timestamps for you.

Comment: Thanks for this command that allowed me to quickly delete all snapshots. `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999` did not delete anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

according to the tmutil man page:

*deletelocalsnapshots {**mountPoint** | date}*

*If a date is specified, delete all local Time Machine snapshots on all mounted disks for the specified date (formatted YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS).  **If a disk is specified, delete all local Time Machine snapshots on the specified disk***

this worked for me:

```
tmutil deletelocalsnapshots /
```

while I ran into another hurdle after deleting snapshots, thanks for teaching me about the CLI interface to Time Machine!