# How to stop macOS updates from taking over the rEFInd boot manager?

Tags: startup, software-update, efi

I have rEFInd installed on the EFI partition of my 2015 MacBook Air. Every time I update macOS, it ends up taking over the bootloader and resetting it to using the macOS operating system. Afterwards, if I hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key while booting up my mac, there is no boot option for rEFInd that I can select. The only way I can bring rEFInd back is to boot up into recovery mode, manually mount my system partition with Disk Utility (as it is encrypted using FileVault), then open Terminal and reinstall rEFInd. It's quite a hassle.

Is there any better way to handle macOS updates?

I have read the section of the rEFInd manual named "Recovering from a Coup Using MacOS" but I didn't find any information in there that was pertinent to my situation. Note that I cannot disable System Integrity Protection (which one of the solutions there requires) as I need to keep it enabled for the software development I do on this system.

Below is the output from the command `diskutil list disk0`.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.1 GB   disk0s2
```

I have Windows, Linux, and macOS 10.15 beta installed to an external drive, so my MacBook's internal drive just has macOS.

Comment: You can install rEFInd in ways other than the default, where rEFInd will appear in the Startup Manager. Before posting an answer, could you add the following to your question: 1) What other operating systems do you have installed? 2) The output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: 1) I have Windows, Linux, and macOS 10.15 beta installed to an external drive, so my MacBook's internal drive just has macOS. 2) Given my answer to 1, my partition layout is typical for macOS 10.14. Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/LbeADFER

Comment: @DavidAnderson I've found an alternative option by installing rEFInd to a separate HFS+ partition on my MacBook's internal drive. It took some work to make it happen though since resizing an APFS container is difficult. (I needed to use `tmutil` both to remove my Time Machine backup as a backup destination and then delete _every single_ local snapshot first!) I think that may have been the direction you were going in. If so, feel free to post that method as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Yes, ether install rEFInd on a new HFS+, FAT or EFI partition. FAT has the advantage of being able to select the default operating system to boot from any installed operating system.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'm not sure what you mean when talking about the advantage of using FAT over HFS+. Can you clarify?

Comment: Some users prefer to select the default operating system while booted to the current operating system. The rEFInd boot manager by default requires you to select an operating system when the computer starts up (or restarts). The selected operating system then become the default. Some users have reported this is hard to do with wireless keyboards and mice. To select the default from the current operating system, the partition containing rEFInd has to be accessible by all operating systems. Windows, macOS and Linux operating systems can read and write to FAT formatted partitions.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I don't think my question is a duplicate of the question you linked to. That question is asking how to fix a different problem than mine, and the solution you posted is different than the solution I just used to fix my problem. The one similarity is resizing the APFS container on my internal drive to make room for an extra partition, but a) that was _hard_ due to Time Machine and required a lot of extra steps not mentioned in your answer, and b) no changes to refind.conf were necessary for me as I always want rEFInd to be my default bootloader, hence my original question.

Comment: Just so you know: Duplicates have to do with the answers being the same. The questions can be different. But, in this case the answers were different enough, that I changed my mind and posted a new answer. If you still feel my answer is still inaccurate, you can edit the answer and make additions and/or corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, rEFInd is installed in the EFI partition. Another option is to install rEFInd in a new small "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" volume. This will allow rEFInd to appear in the Startup Manager.

Below are the steps. The commands need to be entered into a Terminal application window.

1. Create the new volume. The `diskutil` command, shrinks the APFS container (121100M, i.e. 121.1 GB) by 300 MB (120800M) and creates the new 300 MB "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" volume labeled "Macintosh HD via rEFInd".

   ```
   sudo diskutil ap resizeContainer disk1 120800M JHFS+ "rEFInd" 0
   ```

   After the command completes, restart the Mac.

   > Note:  If you get an error message which includes the phrase *"perhaps caused by APFS Snapshot usage by Time Machine"*, then see [Neil's own answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321533/cant-resize-apfs-container-not-enough-free-space-in-container-due-to-apfs-limi/321542#321542) to the question: [Can't resize APFS Container: Not enough free space in Container due to APFS limits or tidemarks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321533/cant-resize-apfs-container-not-enough-free-space-in-container-due-to-apfs-limi).
2. Download the rEFInd Boot Manager software from this [SourceForge web site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/). Enter the following commands to install the software to the "Macintosh HD via rEFInd" volume.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.11.4
   ./refind-install --ownhfs /dev/disk0s3
   ```

   > Note: The error message `Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc` was expected and can be ignored.
3. (Optional) Use the command below to navigate to the folder containing the `refind.conf` file.

   ```
   cd "/Volumes/rEFInd/System/Library/CoreServices"
   ```

   Add write permissions to the CoreServices folder and the refind.conf file.

   ```
   sudo  chmod  a+w  .  refind.conf
   ```
4. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appears. Next, hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key and select to boot from the `rEFInd` volume.

Comment: Very thorough, thank you! And just for any future readers who might not already know this, holding down `control` when selecting a volume in Apple's Startup Manager sets it to be the default startup disk, which is why this method is advantageous over installing to the EFI partition like I was doing before.